# What does my Uplay level do?

Tags: ubisoft-connect

I understand Steam levels and what they give you but I own a few games on Uplay (including games I own on Steam but have to play through Uplay...) and I noticed that there is a profile leveling system in place. There is also a U points system, which lets me unlock different in-game and other extras. However, it's not directly connected to my level.

So, what does my profile level do exactly and do I get anything for leveling up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i know, there are not many things that change your profile related to your level, but i managed to figure out something.

So one of the features you achieve is the possibillity to choose more badges on your Uplay profile.

[image]

What also might be a little but not really important benefit is that you are on the top of your friends list if you are the highest level of your friends, which is kinda normal. (If leaderboard order is selected)

These are the only things i found on Uplay which are related to the level yet.
The currency of UPlay is Units, you get them while playing (XP too) and spend them for games or discounts. The Level system is just to show your friends the progress on your games and how much you played them. It is not trying to give you benefits like Steam does.